# GraphicsMagick crop PDF

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, graphicsmagick

I've got a 8.5x11 PDF at 300dpi. It has a single UPC label in the top left corner of the PDF.  Imagine that there could be 30 labels on a 1 sheet, but we just have 1 label.

I'm trying to crop the PDF to be just the size of the 1 label. So far I've got this

```
gm convert -density 300 single.pdf out.pdf
```

Which doesn't do any cropping.  When I crop to say 300x100 it makes a 20MB file with 30000 pages.

I have not a clue how to use `-crop` to actually crop to the correct size.  I need it to be 3.5inches by 1.125 inches.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the following input PDF (here converted to a PNG):

[image: wiz.pdf]

the following command will crop the label:

```
gm wiz.pdf -crop 180x50+1+1  cropped.pdf
```

[image: cropped.pdf]

This label is sized `180x50` pixels.

For an `8.5x11in` PDF at 300 PPI you'd have a `2450x3300` pixels PDF (which I doubt you do, but that's another question) and you'd need to use `-crop 1050x337+0+0` (more exactly, `1050x337.5+0+0` -- but you cannot crop half pixels!).

Note, the `+0+0` part crops the top left corner. If you need offset to the right by `N` pixels and to the bottom by `M` pixels use `+N+M`...

---

### Using ImageMagick instead...

You could also use ImageMagick's `convert` command:

```
convert wiz.pdf[180x50+1+1] cropped.pdf
```

---

### Comment about image sizes...

One additional comment about this remark:

> *"I have not a clue how to use `-crop` to actually crop to the correct size."*

There is no other real size for raster images than *pixels*. `ABC` pixels wide and `XYZ` pixels high...

There is no such thing as an absolute, real size for a digital image that you can measure in *inches*... unless you additionally can state the resolution at which a given image is rendered on a display or a print device!

An `8.50x11in` sized image at 300 PPI will translate to `2550x3300` pixels.
However, if your image does not contain this amount of pixels (which is the *real*, *absolute* size of any raster image), you may still be able to render it at 300 PPI -- but its size in inches will be different from `8.5x11in`!

So, whenever you want to crop, use the absolute number of pixels you want. Don't use resolution/density at all on your command line!

Comment: @SeanClark: Hmm? So this answer was worth an 'accept', but not an 'upvote'?

Comment: Well explained. I can add an upvote... there you go!